James email server javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed, but I am able send the emails
I am able to send the emails using java program to james email server, but I am unable to read the emails from inbox and I am getting following exception
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:732)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at emailtest.emailtest.EmailClient.checkInbox(EmailClient.java:56)
    at emailtest.emailtest.EmailClient.main(EmailClient.java:88)

debug message
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
Show INBOX for largepayloadrejecct2@soa-mq-target.subnet2ad1phx.paasinfratoophx.com
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAP: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "soa-mq-target.subnet2ad1phx.paasinfratoophx.com", port 143, isSSL false
* OK JAMES IMAP4rev1 Server soa-mq-target.subnet2ad1phx.paasinfratoophx.com is ready.
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY NAMESPACE SEARCHRES QRESYNC UNSELECT ACL ENABLE QUOTA WITHIN SASL-IR CHILDREN UIDPLUS AUTH=PLAIN IDLE LITERAL+ I18NLEVEL=1 MOVE IMAP4REV1 ANNOTATION ESEARCH
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect login, host=soa-mq-target.subnet2ad1phx.paasinfratoophx.com, user=largepayloadrejecct2, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed. Authentication failed.
DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "soa-mq-target.subnet2ad1phx.paasinfratoophx.com", port 143, isSSL false
* OK JAMES IMAP4rev1 Server soa-mq-target.subnet2ad1phx.paasinfratoophx.com is ready.
B0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY NAMESPACE SEARCHRES QRESYNC UNSELECT ACL ENABLE QUOTA WITHIN SASL-IR CHILDREN UIDPLUS AUTH=PLAIN IDLE LITERAL+ I18NLEVEL=1 MOVE IMAP4REV1 ANNOTATION ESEARCH
B0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect login, host=soa-mq-target.subnet2ad1phx.paasinfratoophx.com, user=largepayloadrejecct2, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: B1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed. Authentication failed.
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed. Authentication failed.
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:732)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at emailtest.emailtest.EmailClient.checkInbox(EmailClient.java:56)
    at emailtest.emailtest.EmailClient.main(EmailClient.java:88)

the program I have used to read the emails
package emailtest.emailtest;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class EmailClient  extends Authenticator
{
  public static final int SHOW_MESSAGES = 1;
  public static final int CLEAR_MESSAGES = 2;
  public static final int SHOW_AND_CLEAR =
    SHOW_MESSAGES + CLEAR_MESSAGES;
  
  protected String from;
  protected Session session;
  protected PasswordAuthentication authentication;
  
  public EmailClient(String user, String host,String pass)   {
    this(user, host,pass, false);
  }
  
  public EmailClient(String user, String host,String pass, boolean debug)  {
    from = user + '@' + host;
    authentication = new PasswordAuthentication(user, pass);
  
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.user", user);  
    props.put("mail.host", host);
    props.put("mail.port", 143);
    props.put("mail.debug", debug ? "true" : "false");  
    props.put("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    session = Session.getInstance(props, this);
  }
  
  public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()  {
    return authentication;
  }
   
  public void checkInbox(int mode)
    throws MessagingException, IOException  {
    if (mode == 0) return;
    boolean show = (mode & SHOW_MESSAGES) > 0;
    boolean clear = (mode & CLEAR_MESSAGES) > 0;
    String action =
      (show ? "Show" : "") +
      (show && clear ? " and " : "") +
      (clear ? "Clear" : "");
    System.out.println(action + " INBOX for " + from);
    Store store = session.getStore("imap");
   // Store store = session.getStore();
    store.connect( "soa-mq-target.subnet2ad1phx.paasinfratoophx.com","largepayloadrejecct2","Adapterqa1");
    Folder root = store.getDefaultFolder();
    Folder inbox = root.getFolder("Inbox");
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
    Message[] msgs = inbox.getMessages();
    if (msgs.length == 0 && show)
    {
      System.out.println("No messages in inbox");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++)
    {
      MimeMessage msg = (MimeMessage)msgs[i];
      if (show)
      {
        System.out.println("    From: " + msg.getFrom()[0]);
        System.out.println(" Subject: " + msg.getSubject());
        System.out.println(" Content: " + msg.getContent());
      }
      if (clear)
      {
        msg.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
      }
    }
    inbox.close(true);
    store.close();
    System.out.println();
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
      // CREATE CLIENT INSTANCES largepayloadrejecct2@soa-mq-target.subnet2ad1phx.paasinfratoophx.com
      EmailClient emailClient = new EmailClient("largepayloadrejecct2", "soa-mq-target.subnet2ad1phx.paasinfratoophx.com","Adapterqa1", true);
         
      // LIST MESSAGES FOR email client
      emailClient.checkInbox(EmailClient.SHOW_MESSAGES);
  }
}

but using this below program I am able to send the emails to the email server.
package emailtest.emailtest;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;


public class EmailSender {
    public EmailSender() {
    }

    public static void sendEmail( String to, String subject, String from, String content) throws Exception{
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", "soa-mq-target.subnet2ad1phx.paasinfratoophx.com"); 
        props.setProperty("mail.user", "largepayloadrejecct4"); 
        props.setProperty("mail.password", "Adapterqa1");

        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        message.addFrom(new Address[] { new InternetAddress("largepayloadrejecct4@soa-mq-target.subnet2ad1phx.paasinfratoophx.com",from)});  // the reply to email address and a logical descriptor of the sender of the email!

        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setContent(content, "text/plain");
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
             new InternetAddress(to));

        transport.connect();
        transport.sendMessage(message,
            message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        transport.close();
        }
        
        public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
            String content = "Some test content.";
            EmailSender.sendEmail("largepayloadrejecct2@soa-mq-target.subnet2ad1phx.paasinfratoophx.com","An interesting message","THE APP72",content);
            System.out.println("email sent ");
        }
   }

Also I have checked the imap is enabled
<imapservers>
   <imapserver enabled="true">

       <jmxName>imapserver</jmxName>
 <bind>soa-mq-target.subnet2ad1phx.paasinfratoophx.com:143</bind>
:
:
 <!-- Set the maximum simultaneous incoming connections for this service -->
       <connectionLimit>0</connectionLimit>

       <!-- Set the maximum simultaneous incoming connections per IP for this service -->
       <connectionLimitPerIP>0</connectionLimitPerIP>

        <plainAuthDisallowed>false</plainAuthDisallowed>
        <auth>
            <plainAuthEnabled>true</plainAuthEnabled>
        </auth>
    </imapserver>

It is saying Authenticate failed but using the same authentication I am able send the emails. In IMAP is there a different way to pass the authentication?
I tried multiple things (Note: ssl is not enabled)

props.put("mail.password" ,"Adapterqa1"). not worked
props.put("mail.imap.password" ,"Adapterqa1"). not worked
directly used store.connect() hardcoded values still no luck

I am not sure what wrong I am doing , please suggest
